# how to fix json response with a link showing as a text in client-side

Tags: next.js, hyperlink, response

I'm sending a json response with a message to client-side. It has a hyplerlink added to another page. But when I print my result in front-end  tag shows as a text. Any idea how to fix the issue.

And this is a NextJs Project

Response Sending code.

```
res.status(500).json({
        status: false,
        msg: `User Is Already Acticated. Please <a href="${
          proto + req.headers.host
        }/login">Login</a>`,
      });
```

[Front-end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a92ZQ.png)

Tried adding `Link` replacing `a`. But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

```
function Example({ response }) {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: response.msg }} />
  );
}
```